# C++ I need to check if a two-digit number contains a 0 or not

Tags: c++, algorithm, math

I am making a program where I need to check if a two-digit number like 76 or 70 contains a 0 or not.

- with `76` the outcome would be false
- with `70` true

I can't seem to make something up and I am still stuck with nothing not knowing how to start.

Comment: Meaning the number is divisible by 10? Your welcome.

Comment: A number contains a zero if it ends in a zero (and is positive) or the number divided by ten contains a zero. Write a loop that repeatedly divides the number by 10 and checks if the number modulo 10 is 0.

Comment: These both assume you already _know_ about remainders and the [modulo operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic#Multiplicative_operators), of course.

Comment: The question is not clear. Do u need to know if the number has 0 at end like 70, 760 but not 704. Or do you want to know if the number has 0 anywhere like 70, 704,401, etc.?

Comment: Do you need to check numbers like `05` also?

Comment: @MyCopy The OP is asking for 2-digits numbers.

Comment: Then there is nothing to ask. A simple modulus by 10 will give the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can convert the number to string and check if first or second char is '0'

```
bool containsZero (int x) {
    string tmp = to_string(x);
    if (tmp[0] == '0' || tmp[1] == '0') 
        return true;
    return false;
 }
```

or divide the number on 10 twice and check if every digit is 0 or not

```
bool containsZero (int x) {
   while (x != 0) 
   { 
        if (x % 10 == 0) 
            return true;
        x = x / 10; 
   } 
   return false; 
}
```

Comment: I've never thought about that, updated it @JanSchultke

Comment: You can simplify the first function to `return tmp[0] == '0' || tmp[1] == '1'`;

Comment: sure @JanSchultke, but I believe it will make the question owner confuse

Answer (score 2):

The only two-digit numbers that contain zeros are those divisible by 10, so

```
bool has_zero = number % 10 == 0;
```

Comment: This only checks whether a two-digit numbers ends with zero. OP is asking whether it **contains** a zero.

Comment: @JanSchultke The two-digit numbers are the numbers between 10 and 99. Not a single one of them has a zero in anything but the last position.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the number is `x`

You can check easily for a two digit number by using the condition:

```
if((x%10==0)||(x/10)%10==0))
{
  //number has zero
}
else
{
   //number does not have zero
}
```

Comment: If the number is guaranteed to be two-digit, then you only need `return !(x % 10 && x / 10)`

Comment: OP has not mentioned if by two digit number he considers numbers which has 0 before them

Answer (score 0):

If it is only for a two-digit number you can do the following inside a function which's return parameter would be a boolean value:

```cpp
bool contains_zero(int num) {
    int rem  = num % 10;
    return rem == 0;
}
```

Comment: I think it's alternative can be ternary operation @MarekR

Comment: the alternative is to write `return (rem == 0);`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check digit by digit, Then the initial logic could be:

- Convert Number to string (To iterate over it)
- Loop over the number
- Check if the single-digit is equal to '0' or not

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main() {
  bool ischeck = false;
  int x = 67;
  string a = to_string(x);

  for(int i=0;i <a.length();i++)
  {
    if(a[i]=='0')
    {
      ischeck = true;
      break;
    }
  }
  if(ischeck)
  {
    cout<<"True\n";
  }
  else{
    cout<<"False\n";
  }

}
```

Else the Logic Explained by @freakish is best. In that case program would be

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main() {
  int x = 70;

  if(x%10==0)
  {
    cout<<"True";
  }
  else{
    cout<<"False";
  }

}
```

The 2nd logic will not work in case of Numbers like "05" or "07" but 1st logic will work in everycase.

Comment: OP is asking for numbers with 2 digits. There is only one digit that can be 0 in a two digit number